# Cannot install Ruby Gem Addressable v2.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, addressable-gem

I am having problems with Ruby. When I try to install addressable, I get told I need ruby 1.9.0 or higher, but as you can see from my rvm list command I run 2.3.1.

Does anyone have any tips? am I doing something wrong?  I've tried running the clean up, and reinstalling but I get the same error.

Any tips you can provide would be great! Thanks!

```
root@server1 [/]# rvm list

rvm rubies
ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

root@server1 [/]# gem install addressable -v '2.4.0'
ERROR:  Error installing addressable:
        addressable requires Ruby version >= 1.9.0.
root@server1 [/]#
```

[image]

Comment: You can first set a default ruby version using rvm --default use 2.3.1 and then try to install addressable.

Comment: Try running `ruby -v` see what your default environment thinks it's actually running.

Comment: And also try `gem env` to see its installation directory and ruby executable version.

Comment: When I run ruby -v here is what I get.

root@server1 [/]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]


Why the discrepency between the two?

Answer (score 0):

First run `rvm use ruby-2.3.1` then `gem install addressible`.

To not have to run this command first, run `rvm alias create ruby-2.3.1`. You may have to run `bash` after that to load the changes. Sometime's it's needed to either run `/bin/bash --login` or change the terminal preferences to login shell in order for RVM commands to work.

Comment: I think this may work, but only in that terminal session, because you issue the first command `rvm use ruby-2.3.1`.  I don't think that changes rvm's configuration at all except for the creation of the alias.  I believe this will *not* fix the problem in new shell invocations.

Comment: I tried ...rvm reset, then  _rvm alias create default ruby-2.3.0_
so when I run RVM list I see **=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]** , but when I run ruby -v I see **ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]**

Comment: Hey, thanks for the /bin/bash --login tip. It worked!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. From your screenshot it seems that Ruby 2.3.0 is installed but you haven't _selected it to be used_ by running `rvm use`.  By the way if you're using Ruby 2.3.0 take a look at the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using the "system" ruby.  This will be obvious when you run `ruby -v`.  It is also evidenced by the fact that your `rvm list` output does not list a Ruby as the "current" Ruby.  So rvm will have a newer Ruby, but it will not be used.

It's possible that creating the default Ruby for rvm will result in that Ruby being loaded whenever you open a terminal.

Also, the terminal needs to be a "login shell", but if this is a problem you should see a message to that effect.

So I suggest doing the following, which should only need to be done once:

```
rvm default ruby-2.3.1
```

...then opening a new terminal and seeing if your `gem` command works correctly there.